# The property 'documents' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. It is giving this error in the code

Tags: flutter

```dart
else {
                  return SliverStaggeredGrid.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                    staggeredTiles: snapshot.data.documents.map(
                            (doc) {
                          return StaggeredTile.count(doc.data["x"], doc
                              .data["y"]);
                        }
                    ).toList(),
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map(
                            (doc) {
                          return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                              image: doc.data["image"],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          );
                        }
                    ).toList(),
                  );
                }
```

I was bringing images to my app

Comment: Why is this question tagged python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle if data is null or not

```
              final documents = snapshot.data?.documents ?? [];
              return SliverStaggeredGrid.count(
                ...
                children: documents.map(
                        (doc) {
                      ...
                    }
                ).toList(),
              );
            }
```